# Behaviour of DateRange?

Tags: bugs, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 12.0.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

The last day of the year is Dec 31st:

```
Table[
  DateValue[#, {"Day", "Month"}] &@(Last@DateRange[DateObject[{year, 1, 1}], DateObject[{year, 12, 31}]]),
  {year, 2020, 2030}]

(*{{31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}, {31, 12}}*)
```

Strange things happen for wildly large years:

```
Table[
  DateValue[#, {"Day", "Month"}] &@(Last@DateRange[DateObject[{year, 1, 1}], DateObject[{year, 12, 31}]]),
  {year, 822663, 822663 + 10}]

 (* {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}} *)
```

Is this supposed to happen or is it a bug? It does not seem to happen when `DateRange` is replaced with `DayRange`.

Comment: It does also work if the dates are provided to ```DateRange``` as {y,m,d} instead of ```DateObject```.

Comment: It seems to break starting with year 559375. Not sure why that number is significant. Maybe something magical like the number of seconds since 1900 to that date exceeds some power of 2? Mysterious.

Comment: I get 559373 as the last working date.

Comment: To be more precise, years after 559373 give a result shifted to the next day. Year 559374 gives Jan 1 559375.

Comment: I also get 559373 as the last working year. I found that `DateObject` with {y, m, d, h} works. Since `DateObject` works with {y, m, d, h}, and `DateRange` works with {y, m, d}, the problem seems to be a subtle bug.

Comment: Should I file a bug report?

Comment: Looks like a good idea. If you do, please post any response you get.

Comment: Done. I'll come back to the question in case I get a reply.

Comment: Got a reply from WRI: this appears to be a bug and it's been registered.